# How to handle User Session in angular 5

Tags: angular

For the backend, I am using Spring Framework with 'Shiro' for authentication,

And for the frontend, I am using Angular 5.

If I am calling my login API from postman than I am getting same user session until I use logout API. (Which is correct)

Postman UI image:
[image]

But when I am calling my login API from my angular 5 than I am getting different user session on every call. (Which is wrong.)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
  private _url:string = "v1/login";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(){
    const data = {userName:"root", password:"root"};
    return this.http.post(this._url,{headers: this.headers},{params : data})
    .subscribe(data => {sessionStorage.setItem("jsessionid",JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).jsessionid)});
  }
}
```

Angular UI image:
[image]

On each call 'jsessionid' is changing as shown in ''

Comment: Do you send the old `jsessionid` value back on successive calls?

Comment: we get that 'jsessionid' from Shiro, so if we call login API from same user session then we will get same 'jsessionid' .
Here when I am calling my login API from angular that time on each call new session is creating. So each time that 'jsessionid' is changing.

Comment: The `jsessionid` value is used to identify the session at the server side. The client must send it back with each call or a new session will be created.

Comment: yes. But I don't know how to send that `jsessionid` on each call from the client side (From angular 5 ).

Comment: I don't know Shiro but typically this is done as a cookie.

Comment: Angular 5 is new for me so I don't know how to handle this problem in angular. And Shiro needs the session for authentication. In normal cases, we handle this authentication using tokens. (Server side is working fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session management will happen automatically.

If we have client on one server and backend on another server at that time we just need to add 'proxy.conf.json' file.
And need to add that file entry in 'package.json' file.

> Important:- Add server url upto the port number in 'proxy.conf.json'. (Server url
>   entry till port number)

```
{
    "/": {
      "target": "https://localhost:30443",
      "secure": false
    }
 }
```

In my case, I was using one extra parameter `/mainlayer` in server URL. (Which was wrong.)

```
{
   "/": {
     "target": "https://localhost:30443/mainlayer",
     "secure": false
   }
}
```

And in `LoginService` class just add that extra parameter.

```
private _url:string = "mainlayer/v1/login";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check "jsessionid" in session storage before sending auth reques.

```
login(){
 const data = {userName:"root", password:"root"};
 if(this.isLoggedIn()){
  return Observable.of(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('jsessionid')))
 }

 return this.http.post(this._url,{headers: this.headers},{params : data});
}

private isLoggedIn(): boolean {
 const result = !!(sessionStorage.getItem('jsessionid'));
 return result;
}
```

Also you need to create auth interceptor https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 1):

Having the proxy has nothing to do with your issue... at least not what you described

Just add

```
this.http.{{requestverb}}({{endpoint}}, {withCredentials: true})
```

eg

```
this.http.get("/posts",{withCredentials:true});
```